# Unable to write manifest 'obj\x86\Release\LAP.exe.manifest'

Tags: c#-4.0

> The process cannot access the file 
>   'C:\Users\Hp-user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8dc5e448f31f476083d05e6470e53421.tmp'

because it is being used by another process.

**LAP** is my project name.the **temp file** which is used in another process not always the same it is getting change whenever i build the project.

When this **error** occur i every time exit the `vs 2010` and then project build successfully only once if i modify the code then this error occur again.

Please help me to get out of this error.

Comment: Pretty obscure, and not that healthy.  Disable your anti-malware product for a while to see if that improves this.  And, of course, document what you use.

Comment: Its working for me.I uninstall Byte Anti Malware and the error does not occur again till now.Thank you @HansPassant.